# Implement a trait for a generic trait

Tags: rust

In Rust, how to implement a Trait for a generic trait?

```rust
trait One<S> {}

trait Two {}

// fails because S isn't contrained
impl<S, T> Two for T where T: One<S> {}
```

---

To clarify, I'm trying to provide the `BitAnd` trait
for a generic `Select` trait.

```rust
struct Thing<S> {
    field: S,
}

trait Select<S> {
    fn select(&self, thing: &Thing<S>) -> bool;
}

struct SelectUnion<S> (Box<dyn Select<S>>, Box<dyn Select<S>>);

// fails because S isn't contrained
impl<S, T> std::ops::BitAnd for T where T: Select<S> {
    type Output = SelectUnion<S>;

    fn bitand(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        SelectUnion(Box::new(self), Box::new(rhs))
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you intending these traits to do? If you search for that error there are tons of results but there isn't a lot to go off of in this question.

Comment: I assume chrysn' answer still follows but have you tried adding a constraint to S? I.e `where S: MyTrait`

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've clarified what this is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sam I've tried that, but that still fails. The trait `S` needs to appear in either the trait being implemented, or "the thing implementing it".

Answer (score 0):

It can't be, and the reason is that it would be ambiguous.

Think of a situation like this:

```rust
struct A;

impl One<u16> for A {}

impl One<u32> for A {}
```

Which of the two `One` implementations would the `Two` be based on? Both satisfy the preconditions for the blanket `Two` implementation, but `Two` can only be implemented once for any type. It's like as if you'd provide two separate `impl Two for A` blocks.

---

edit after the question clarification:

The above still holds, but you may want to try whether you can make Select into a type, possibly by turning it into a wrapper around a selectable.

Comment: In my added clarification, the intent is more obvious. The point is that using `BitAnd` (`Two`) on the `Select` (`One`) trait doesn't care about the `S` parameter. So in that sense, the error is correct; S isn't really constraint. However, I'm forced to mention it for `Select` (`Two`).

Comment: The clarification doesn't change much. Just because the trait doesn't happen to depend on S, neither can the compiler show that, nor is it future-proof.

Granted, it's unlikely that BitAnd will ever grow a method like `fn show_what_i_can_and_into()` that does something like `println!("{:?} can BitAnd with itself into {:?}", type_name_of(Self), type_name_of(Self::Output))`, but if it would, what'd `BitAnd::show_what_i_can_and_into()` do for something that's both `Select<u16>` and `Select<u32>`?